# Source control and working on new version of app

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I use Mercurial/TortoiseHg as my source control.

So far I have a single app and just about to finish the version 1.0. Once V 1.0 goes live, we already have features lined-up ready to be programmmed for the next version.

It is a phone app and right now V1.0 will be free but might want to make V2.0 paid and also later might make some minor bug/fixes updates to Free version.

I am not sure how the bug fixing will work while V2.0 is in progress.

**My question is:**

Do I need to fork or branch my repository from the point of V1.0 or I simply keep adding features to my current repository?
Whatever I need to do, I would also like to know why I need to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

Tag the revision that you release as v1.0

```
hg update -r <revision that's 1.0>
hg tag v1.0
hg ci -m 'Created V1.0 Tag'
```

Make a branch for any bug fixes that will go on top of that. This could be when you release V1.0, or when you have the first bug fix for it.

```
hg update v1.0 (or ideally the revision that added the V1.0 tag if it's immediately after V1.0)
hg branch release_v1
<Possibly do bug fix>
hg ci
```

Go back to the default branch to continue development of v2.

```
hg update default
<carry on working>
```

When you've got a bug-fix for v1

```
hg update release_v1
<do bug fix>
```

Then merge forward bug fixes from v1.x to v2.x

```
hg update default
hg merge release_v1
hg ci -m 'Merged V1 bug fixes into V2'
```

You create new tags as you do new releases. The `release_v1` branch just keeps going, accumulating bug fixes, being merged into `default` (your development branch) when necessary. Just make sure you're on the default branch when you merge as that determines which branch name the merge change-set has.

---

Editted to add that this is a variation on the `stable`/`default` work-flow that someone else mentioned, but I like to have a branch for each major release as then I can have more than one major release accepting bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks Paul for detailed steps. Yes, I would also prefer to do create a separate branch for each version. Are there any cons using that method over stable/default variant?

Comment: It is stable/default, except stable is called release_v1. It changes a bit when you release version 2, because now you have release_v1, release_v2 & default, but you still work in much the same way. Bug fixes go into the earliest branch that makes sense, and are merged forward.

Answer (score 2):

A common workflow is to have two branches, `stable` and `default`.  You add new features to `default` and merge to `stable` when you're ready to release a new version.  Live bugs are fixed on the `stable` branch and merged back into `default`.

[This page](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/) describes it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a branch for 2.0, add your additions, and either merge them into 1.0 when they're done or create a tagged version of 1.0 to keep for archival purposes.

You keep them separate because you want to be able to recover the 1.0 version in case there are bug fixes needed or a new deployment.

Comment: Thanks. What is tagged version? I will look into branching. So when I branch out say V2.0 and the do a merge, I merge changes of V2.0 into 1.0 or 1.0 in 2.0? Sorry but this merging and source control as a whole is bit confusing to me.

Comment: Read the Subversion "Red Bean" book.  It's got a nice discussion about version control, even if it pre-dates Mercurial.

Comment: That sounds all kinds of backwards to me. It puts version 1 as the default branch, even though most new work will go towards version 2 and it merges version 2's new features into version 1. This is how you get into trouble IMHO.

Comment: Right - merge 2 back into 1.  I agree with Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats, the thing is that once your app goes live you will probably have to fix bugs, and do some minor updates, but fixing such bugs or minor updates could interfere with your work on 2.0 as such it would be wise to simply branch, fix bugs as they come and propagate to 2.0 if the need arises.